# session is retriveing values of older session in jsp scriptlets

Tags: java, jsp, session, csrf

1)      When user logs into our system via SSO, we generate a random token and keep that in session at server side  code looks like, so it will be generated only once just after user logs in

```
if(slingRequest.getSession().getAttribute("csrfToken") == null){
                            UUID uuidRandom = UUID.randomUUID();
                            String Guid = "_" + uuidRandom.toString();
                            log.info("Random CSRF number Generated is "+Guid);
                            slingRequest.getSession().setAttribute("csrfToken",Guid);
               }
```

2)  On every page , we are reading from session and keeping this value in a hidden field code looks like

```
 <%String csrfToken="";
if(null != request.getSession() && null != request.getSession().getAttribute("csrfToken")){
csrfToken=(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("csrfToken");
pageContext.setAttribute("csrfToken",csrfToken);
 }
 %>
<input type="text" id="csrfToken" value="${csrfToken}"    style="display:none;" name="csrfToken">
```

3)  On every POST request we are sending this csrfToken which is stored in hidden field to server and validate it at backend with the values retrieved from session at server side, if it’s is same then request is valid otherwise it’s not.

```
 if(csrfToken.equals(request.getSession().getAttribute("csrfToken").toString()  ))
```

4)  On logout we invalidate the session and remove the token from session.

```
       request.getSession().removeAttribute("csrfToken");
       request.getSession().removeAttribute("globalAccountHolder");
       request.getSession().invalidate();
```

Issue:
Sometimes pagesource/hidden field value is shown as same as it was in previous session, which is before log out value. i.e step 2 shows older value and when step 3 gets executed the matches of token fails, but if we reload the page using Cntrl+R then hidden field value is shown correctly and works. So not able to understand if this is browser caching problem for a page??

Tried Solution: As a solution for this we have set no-cache in our response headers, but this doesn’t work .

Is there any other solution you can think of like including any meta-tag in page header, or some otherthing?
ALso this issue i am facing sometimes only not everytime

Comment: Can you plz post the _logout_ code to your question?

Comment: please add the code that you write to logout from the system. I think problem with your Logout Code. you are not flushing you session at the time of logout. Thanx @Pallavi

Comment: Code for removing form session    request.getSession().removeAttribute("csrfToken");
  request.getSession().removeAttribute("globalAccountHolder");
  request.getSession().invalidate();

Comment: session will not saved by the cache after you invalidate the session it must not seen in the cache. Problem is not in the browser. As a quick solution when login you can remove csrfToken if that is not null. and save the new one after that. as a quick fix you can do that.

Comment: ok, but why if we I do Cntr+R and reload the page, it picks up correct value??